# Regex for matching every line enclosed in curly brackets

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match every single line within curly brackets, and I'm struggling to capture what I want. To give an example, if I have this text:

```
{
  this is a line,
    this = another line,
    this is the third line!
this is, indeed, another line
},
round two: {
we're now on the second pair of brackets,
  and this is the final line.
}
```

Then I want to match and capture a total of six lines:

- `this is a line,`
- `this = another line,`
- `this is the third line!`
- `this is, indeed, another line`
- `we're now on the second pair of brackets,`
- `and this is the final line.`

So far my current idea is trying to match "curly bracket" -> "anything" -> "line" -> "anything" -> "curly bracket", i.e. something like this:

`{(?s)[^}]*(^([^}^\n]+)$)(?s)[^}]*}`

But that only matches one line per pair of curly brackets, rather than *every* line.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

---

EDIT: Updated the example to include preceding text before one of the opening curly braces and varying whitespace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Edited my post to show what I've got so far.

Comment: Have you tried just NOT matching the curly braces? `[^\{\}]+`

Comment: @Dunois That will match the entire content in the curly brackets, not just one line at a time.

Comment: Is the input well formed? ie, are there any `}` without an preceding `{`?

Comment: @Bohemian We can assume the input is well-formed.

Comment: Maybe just match the two spaces for each of the lines required capturing those? `^  (.*)$` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/fvFF5Z/1

Comment: @MDR The whitespace can be of arbitrary/varying length.

Comment: Did your file start out as a JSON document?  It looks a bit like an array of objects.  If so, it would be better to use a JSON parser to select these items.

Comment: @terafl0ps Unfortunately no, it didn't start out as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match lines that don't contain a brace:

```
^[^{}\r\n]+$
```

The multiline flag is to be set (`/m`). Alternatively, insert `(?m)` at the beginning of the regex.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WwO7eV/5/)

The regex reads, "match the beginning of the line followed by one or more characters other than `{`, `}`, `\r` and `\n`, followed by the end of the line".

To exclude leading spaces in each matched line you can modify the regex slightly:

```
^\s*\K[^{}\r\n]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WwO7eV/6/)

`\K` resets the starting point of the match, excluding any previously-consumed characters. `\K` is not available with all regex engines.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: @Step If you really need to match lines not containing braces you need `(?m)^[^{}\r\n]+$`

Comment: @Wiktor, thanks. Much better. I'll make the change.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming input is well formed:

```
([^{\n](?=[^{]+}))+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/FSiGOz62TcCeNj)

Comment: This seems to match opening curly braces and also isn't robust to text preceding the curly braces: https://regex101.com/r/fvFF5Z/2

Comment: That doesn't match the opening curly brace anymore but it's still not robust to text preceding opening curly braces.

Comment: @step ok, sorted now. see link for demo.